# Need a Chinese/English technology translation website 请求汉英电脑技术词典的网站

Tags: translation, technology

When speaking to Chinese folks in the Bay Area, when you hit a technology word ("load average", "I/O thruput"), you just break into English.

Is there a good site with translations for ALL the fancy words? The Google doesn't always do a good job (surprisingly!), and searching has come up blank.

在美国，跟中国人聊聊电脑界，常用半中半英的chinglish。 对港陆台人不合适。有没有电脑界的汉英技术词典网站吗？美国霸王大哥、中国百度小弟都翻不成。

Comment: [電腦名詞譯名](http://www.iicm.org.tw/term/)

Comment: We don't speak 电脑界, you may use 跟中国人聊聊计算机行业, or 跟中国人聊聊互联网. You can use 计算机**词汇/名词**, 互联网**词汇/名词** for **the words relative to computer**, e.g.: 计算机汉英词典, 计算机行业汉英词典, 计算机专业汉英词典.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me as a native Chinese speaker often runs into the similar trouble. The problem is that computer technology came to us as English with the original language describing it. All of those translation come after it, those good ones even later, and also they would mainly be used for education purpose in text book. And as a programmer myself I always find difficult to find the correct Chinese word for those new terms came into the industry.

There were also quite some time when I tried to use the Chinese term while talking with other Chinese that studied abroad and they just looked at me with a confused expression on their face. So I don't bother doing so anymore.

Also during those time that I worked for foreign invested software companies in China, even most of the co-workers are Chinese we would still mix English in our conversation, classic examples are 'bugs', I run into no Chinese calling it 缺陷 but only myself, and even that was trying to tell an American what's the Chinese word for 'bug' and it felt so wrong to me at that time when I speak it. So I would say don't bother to find such a thing. :)

**EDIT:**

As OP insist I went on searching such a thing. There was actually a term on this '计算机专业英语', and I recall I indeed need to pass the test for this one back in the university study. So I went on googling '计算机专业英语词典', like I said it's mainly for educational purpose and for text book, those things are so out of date like at least four years ago, also I suspect it would consider as out of date even back at that time.

Again it looks all of those tools/resources are trying to targeting students, some of them even are just a simple copy from text book.

There is this one looks promising main has the potential as a candidate, but as it's a mobile app I didn't try it myself: [外教社计算机英语词典](http://cidian.dict.cn/wjs/sc54.html)

Comment: I agree, but not too long ago I was chatting up a friend in China, and he dropped some bizarre term on me. Can't remember what it was, but the translation ended up being "Load Average". SERIOUSLY? There's a Chinese word for "LOAD AVERAGE"?!?!?! I was amazed. The ENGLISH term doesn't even make sense ("the average number of jobs in the run queue over a period of time" is somehow called "load average").

While it may not be completely useful, when someone drops "load average" on me, or I want to drop "load average" on them, it might come in handy.

Comment: @MarkGerolimatos, I've updated the answer but it might still not what you are looking for

Comment: An app? No, that's PERFECT! Of course, it probably downloads some spyware from 公安局, but how is that different from the NSA downloading spyware on everything? :-) (hello, NSA!)

Comment: @MarkGerolimatos Ha I hope this is clean as it claims to be some official stuff. Btw side topic while you trying to googling in Chinese, different with English as you know it does not separate word with space, which make it totally different. My trick is always add spaces between those Chinese key words processed by your brain rather than hope search engine can help you do the trick. You will notice the instant differences which show a more accurate search result. So in this case I Googled '计算机 专业 英语 词典'.

Comment: Ah, okay, makes sense. I must admit, I was sort of guessing that The Google did the word splitting internally...guess not.

Comment: from my observation it does try its best to split words, but it's still a guess and it can't read your mind, I think they are facing the same problem with other languages that generally do not use spaces, Japanese, Korean etc.